# C# webservices using unmanaged C++ dll have iis error

Tags: c#, c++, web-services, wrapper

I have an C# desktop application which using C++ dll. It's running on .NET 3.5 and working good. The wrapper class using Pinvoke like following:

```
[DllImport("shapelib", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void SHPGetInfo(IntPtr hSHP, ref int pnEntities,
        ref ShapeType pshpType, double[] adfMinBound, double[] adfMaxBound);
```

All of wrapper and controller of this application is on class.
Now i want to change this application to webservices app. So i build a .net webservices to call a controller and wrapper class. When i run this webservices application on iis 7, Everytime using Pinvoke to call unmanaged dll, i get error: "w3wp error".
I used debug diagnostic tool and i show error like following:

```
In w3wp__DefaultAppPool__PID__1280__Date__11_17_2013__Time_12_37_22PM__300__Second_Chance_Exception_C0000374.dmp the assembly instruction at ntdll!RtlReportCriticalFailure+57 in C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll from Microsoft Corporation has caused an unknown exception (0xc0000374) on thread 27
```

Please help me! Any ideal is appreciate!

PS: thread 27 is
Thread 27 - System ID 2032
Entry point   mscorwks!Thread::intermediateThreadProc 
Create time   11/17/2013 12:37:17 PM 
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 0:0:0.62 
Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 0:0:0.46

Full Call Stack

Function     Arg 1     Arg 2     Arg 3     Arg 4   Source 
ntdll!RtlReportCriticalFailure+57     c0000374     76facdd8     0324e118     76f9481b
ntdll!RtlpReportHeapFailure+21     00000002     7f19152a     00000000     001e0000
ntdll!RtlpLogHeapFailure+a1     00000008     001e0000     021fc1e8     00000000
ntdll!RtlFreeHeap+64     001e0000     00000000     021fc1f0     76007250
AcXtrnal!NS_FaultTolerantHeap::APIHook_RtlFreeHeap+61     001e0000     00000000     021fc1f0     0324e184
ole32!CRetailMalloc_Free+1c     760066bc     021fc1f0     0324e194     79de7b81   d:\w7rtm\com\ole32\com\class\memapi.cxx @ 687 
ole32!CoTaskMemFree+13     021fc1f0     0324e47c     0324e3d0     79deb192   d:\w7rtm\com\ole32\com\class\memapi.cxx @ 475 
mscorwks!DefaultMarshalOverrides::ReturnCLRFromNative+35     0324e424     0324e46c     34afa0ec     00f51d3c
mscorwks!RunML+949     00f51d51     0324e46c     0324e428     0324e47c
mscorwks!NDirectGenericStubPostCall+194     00b30ff0     0324e4fc     01883ad8     00f51d51
mscorwks!NDirectGenericStubReturnFromCall+1f     34afa534     018807c0     0ff3af10     00000000
mscorwks!MethodDesc::DoPrestub+515     001e0000     00000000     00b35980     0324e77c
AcXtrnal!NS_FaultTolerantHeap::APIHook_RtlFreeHeap+61     001e0000     00000000     00b35980     0324e748
kernel32!HeapFree+14     001e0000     00000000     79b548ba     34afa474
mscorwks!EEHeapFree+98     001e0000     00000000     00b35980     0324e790
mscorwks!EEHeapFreeInProcessHeap+22     857a0af4     29840fc0     ff000e81     75ff0c75
0x80000000`00000000     75ff0c75     9be85008     5dffffff     900008c2

0x80000000`00000000     9be85008     5dffffff     900008c2     c2ca9090
ole32!DeleteACEFromStreamACL+4d     3aec79d0     fadb79de     fadb79d0     fb4e79d0   d:\w7rtm\com\ole32\com\accctrl\caccctrl.cxx @ 2425 
0x80000000`00000000     fadb79d0     fadb79d0     b9f879d0     fadb79bc

0x80000000`00000000     fadb79d0     b9f879d0     fadb79bc     fadb79d0
0x80000000`00000000     b9f879d0     fadb79bc     fadb79d0     4db479d0

0x80000000`00000000     fadb79bc     fadb79d0     4db479d0     490879b5
0x80000000`00000000     fadb79d0     4db479d0     490879b5     fadb79b7

0x80000000`00000000     4db479d0     490879b5     fadb79b7     fadb79d0
0x80000000`00000000     490879b5     fadb79b7     fadb79d0     fadb79d0

0x4db479d0     fadb79b7     fadb79d0     fadb79d0     012279d0

0x490879b5     fadb79d0     fadb79d0     012279d0     4dd779d8

0x80000000`00000000     fadb79d0     012279d0     4dd779d8     fadb79da
0x80000000`00000000     012279d0     4dd779d8     fadb79da     d14079d0

0x80000000`00000000     4dd779d8     fadb79da     d14079d0     fadb79b5
0x012279d0     fadb79da     d14079d0     fadb79b5     3aec79d0
0x4dd779d8     d14079d0     fadb79b5     3aec79d0     fadb79de
0x80000000`00000000     fadb79b5     3aec79d0     fadb79de     fadb79d0

0x80000000`00000000     3aec79d0     fadb79de     fadb79d0     fb4e79d0
0x80000000`00000000     fadb79de     fadb79d0     fb4e79d0     fac779d0

0x3aec79d0     fadb79d0     fb4e79d0     fac779d0     fadb79d0

0x80000000`00000000     fb4e79d0     fac779d0     fadb79d0     fadb79d0
0x80000000`00000000     fac779d0     fadb79d0     fadb79d0     b9f879d0

0x80000000`00000000     fadb79d0     fadb79d0     b9f879d0     fadb79bc
0x80000000`00000000     fadb79d0     b9f879d0     fadb79bc     fadb79d0

0x80000000`00000000     b9f879d0     fadb79bc     fadb79d0     4db479d0
0x80000000`00000000     fadb79bc     fadb79d0     4db479d0     490879b5

0x80000000`00000000     fadb79d0     4db479d0     490879b5     fadb79b7
0x80000000`00000000     4db479d0     490879b5     fadb79b7     5a0c79d0

0x80000000`00000000     490879b5     fadb79b7     5a0c79d0     dfb079f7
0x4db479d0     fadb79b7     5a0c79d0     dfb079f7     012279b5
0x490879b5     5a0c79d0     dfb079f7     012279b5     4dd779d8
0x80000000`00000000     dfb079f7     012279b5     4dd779d8     fadb79da

0x5a0c79d0     012279b5     4dd779d8     fadb79da     d14079d0

0x80000000`00000000     4dd779d8     fadb79da     d14079d0     fadb79b5
0x012279b5     fadb79da     d14079d0     fadb79b5     3aec79d0
0x4dd779d8     d14079d0     fadb79b5     3aec79d0     dfb079de
0x80000000`00000000     fadb79b5     3aec79d0     dfb079de     ac7679b5

0x80000000`00000000     3aec79d0     dfb079de     ac7679b5     fb4e79bf
0x80000000`00000000     dfb079de     ac7679b5     fb4e79bf     fac779d0

0x3aec79d0     ac7679b5     fb4e79bf     fac779d0     fadb79d0

0x80000000`00000000     fb4e79bf     fac779d0     fadb79d0     4b1179d0
0x80000000`00000000     fac779d0     fadb79d0     4b1179d0     b9f879c0

0x80000000`00000000     fadb79d0     4b1179d0     b9f879c0     fadb79bc
0x80000000`00000000     4b1179d0     b9f879c0     fadb79bc     fadb79d0

0x80000000`00000000     b9f879c0     fadb79bc     fadb79d0     4db479d0
0x4b1179d0     fadb79bc     fadb79d0     4db479d0     4b2779b5
0x80000000`00000000     fadb79d0     4db479d0     4b2779b5     fadb79c0

0x80000000`00000000     4db479d0     4b2779b5     fadb79c0     fadb79d0
0x80000000`00000000     4b2779b5     fadb79c0     fadb79d0     fadb79d0

0x4db479d0     fadb79c0     fadb79d0     fadb79d0     012279d0

0x4b2779b5     fadb79d0     fadb79d0     012279d0     4dd779d8

0x80000000`00000000     fadb79d0     012279d0     4dd779d8     fadb79da
0x80000000`00000000     012279d0     4dd779d8     fadb79da     f89d79d0

0x80000000`00000000     4dd779d8     fadb79da     f89d79d0     296879bd
0x012279d0     fadb79da     f89d79d0     296879bd     52d079c1
0x4dd779d8     f89d79d0     296879bd     52d079c1     242f79b5
0x80000000`00000000     296879bd     52d079c1     242f79b5     23df79d7

0x80000000`00000000     52d079c1     242f79b5     23df79d7     dfb079d7
0x296879bd     242f79b5     23df79d7     dfb079d7     8de079b5
0x52d079c1     23df79d7     dfb079d7     8de079b5     b44679b6
0x242f79b5     dfb079d7     8de079b5     b44679b6     23ef79e5
0x23df79d7     8de079b5     b44679b6     23ef79e5     7a8279d7
0x80000000`00000000     b44679b6     23ef79e5     7a8279d7     e24679bd

0x80000000`00000000     23ef79e5     7a8279d7     e24679bd     7add79b5
0x80000000`00000000     7a8279d7     e24679bd     7add79b5     e1b079bd

0x23ef79e5     e24679bd     7add79b5     e1b079bd     8b5579b5

System_ni+5279d7     7add79b5     e1b079bd     8b5579b5     8b5756ec

0x80000000`00000000     e1b079bd     8b5579b5     8b5756ec     ff85087d
0x7add79b5     8b5579b5     8b5756ec     ff85087d     840ff78b
0x80000000`00000000     8b5756ec     ff85087d     840ff78b     00038ec7

0x80000000`00000000     ff85087d     840ff78b     00038ec7     8514478b
0x80000000`00000000     840ff78b     00038ec7     8514478b     0c4d8bc0

0x80000000`00000000     00038ec7     8514478b     0c4d8bc0     083b0f74
0x80000000`00000000     8514478b     0c4d8bc0     083b0f74     483b0b72

0x00038ec7     0c4d8bc0     083b0f74     483b0b72     5f067304

0x80000000`00000000     083b0f74     483b0b72     5f067304     08c25d5e
0x0c4d8bc0     483b0b72     5f067304     08c25d5e     74ff8500
0x083b0f74     5f067304     08c25d5e     74ff8500     760e390b
0x483b0b72     08c25d5e     74ff8500     760e390b     10768b5b
0x5f067304     74ff8500     760e390b     10768b5b     f575f685
0x08c25d5e     760e390b     10768b5b     f575f685     e7ebc033
0x74ff8500     10768b5b     f575f685     e7ebc033     4415ff56
0x760e390b     f575f685     e7ebc033     4415ff56     8b7a0af2
0x10768b5b     e7ebc033     4415ff56     8b7a0af2     74f685f0
0x80000000`00000000     4415ff56     8b7a0af2     74f685f0     08be8318

0x80000000`00000000     8b7a0af2     74f685f0     08be8318     00000002
0x4415ff56     74f685f0     08be8318     00000002     fcde850f
0x80000000`00000000     08be8318     00000002     fcde850f     468b0001
0x74f685f0     00000002     fcde850f     468b0001     0fc08508
0x08be8318     fcde850f     468b0001     0fc08508     01fcc184

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is a problem with the memory allocation on the heap in the unmanaged code which results to the .net framework failing trying to release the allocated memory from the heap. The .Net framework uses different protocol to allocate memory and free memory between managed code and unmanaged code.

You should check your unmanaged C++ dll and replace where you allocate memory (using New or Malloc) and replace it with [CoTaskMemAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692727%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Then ensure that your Pinvoke declaration returns the pointer to the allocated memory, which you must manually release when done with it.

Comment: I friend of mine also had a problem using a tiff C++ splitter/converter. He solved the problem by ensuring that all the .Net projects are build explicitly for X86. It might not be related to your problem but worth looking at. Good luck Truong.